# How to identify if my Polymer.dart Component is still the document.activeElement?

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I have a CustomPassword component and want to provide a method `isActive` that allows you to retrieve if the component is still the active element on this website.

**Example Code:**

*custom_password.html*

```
<polymer-element name="custom-password">
  <template>
    <div>Other things here</div>
    <input id="password-field" type="password" value="{{value}}">
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="custom_password.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

*custom_password.dart*

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('custom-password')
class CustomPassword extends PolymerElement {

  @published
  String value;

  CustomPassword.created() : super.created() {
  }

  bool isActive() {
    // TODO figure out if the CustomPassword element is still active.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use `isActive` as an event handler? It looks a bit weird that you pass an event and return a value.

Comment: Actually we use it after a blur event. I converted it to isActive to have a simplified example. Here you can find the b-secret implementation: https://github.com/blossom/bee/blob/master/lib/components/secret/secret.dart#L76

Comment: I understand. Do you really need to compare the `hashcode`? The hashcode is not guaranteed and not even supposed to be unique.

Comment: You are right. I wouldn't need to compare them by hashCode. Internally the hashCode is used to identify if two objects point to the same element? see https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-dom-html.Element#id_hashCode

Answer (score 7):

With a help from the [Polymer Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/polymer-dev/LpGi0v7YYeQ) I was able to come up with a solution:

For browsers with shadow DOM support it works out of the box by comparing
the hashCode of the `document.activeElement` with the components hashCode.

For browsers without shadow DOM support the password field will be the
active element. The trick here is to wrap the `document.activeElement` in order to compare it to the wrapped `passwordField`.

**Example:**

*custom_password.dart*

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:js' as js;

@CustomTag('custom-password')
class CustomPassword extends PolymerElement {

  @published
  String value;

  CustomPassword.created() : super.created() {
  }

  bool isActive() {
      var passwordField = $['password-field'];
      var activeElement = js.context.callMethod('wrap', [document.activeElement]);

      // For Browsers with shadow DOM support the shadowRoot.host matches while
      // for Browsers without shadow DOM support the password field match.
      if (activeElement.hashCode != hashCode &&
          activeElement.hashCode != passwordField.hashCode) {
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```dart
bool isActive(event) {
  return document.activeElement == this;
}
```

This only works in browsers with native Shadow DOM support.
I haven't tested it but this probably only works when your `<custom-password>` element is in the light DOM and not inside the `<template>` of another polymer element like `<app-element>` if you use one.

The current polyfill seems not to work correctly and you get the input element back instead of the Polymer element.

These issues contains information about how activeElement works with Polymer elements
- https://github.com/Polymer/ShadowDOM/issues/478
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=18982
- https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=20165

and also this paragraph
- http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/#active-element